# Using String-array in Pager adapter

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I'm creating Slider adapter in my Android app and I have to use strings from strings.xml. I thought that using **context.getResources().getStringArray()** will help me, but it doesn't work. I have the same problem with listAdapter, but I think that I'm making the same mistake in two cases.
Have You got any idea?

**Slider adapter.class**

```
public class SliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

static Resources res = null;
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


public SliderAdapter(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;

}

public int [] slide_images = {
        R.drawable.ecu_start,
        R.drawable.ecu_version


};

String[] slide_headings = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.p06_heading);


String[] slide_descs = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.p06_desc);


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return slide_headings.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view == (RelativeLayout) object;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_layout, container, false);




    ImageView slideImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_image);
    TextView slideHeading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_heading);
    TextView slideDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_desc);

    slideImageView.setImageResource(slide_images[position]);
    slideHeading.setText(slide_headings[position]);
    slideDescription.setText(slide_descs[position]);

    container.addView(view);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);
}
}
```

**Logcat:**

> 06-16 01:45:01.834 14492-14492/com.example.jacek.hondadiagnostic E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.example.jacek.hondadiagnostic, PID: 14492
>                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jacek.hondadiagnostic/com.example.jacek.hondadiagnostic.Tipsy.P06_vtec_conversion}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this  :

```
public class SliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

static Resources res = null;
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


public SliderAdapter(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;

    slide_headings = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.p06_heading);
    slide_descs = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.p06_desc);
}

public int [] slide_images = {
        R.drawable.ecu_start,
        R.drawable.ecu_version


};

String[] slide_headings  ;


String[] slide_descs ;


@Override
public int getCount() {
  if(slide_headings==null)return 0;
    return slide_headings.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view == (RelativeLayout) object;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_layout, container, false);




    ImageView slideImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_image);
    TextView slideHeading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_heading);
    TextView slideDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_desc);

    slideImageView.setImageResource(slide_images[position]);
    slideHeading.setText(slide_headings[position]);
    slideDescription.setText(slide_descs[position]);

    container.addView(view);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);
}
  }
```